# Opencv, remap: save and load map1 and map2 from file

Tags: c++, opencv, remap

For better performance i want to calculate map1 and map2 only once and then use it with remap(). Both maps are  of type CV_32FC1. I tried to save the maps as .bmp images or .exr files and then load it like this:

```
cv::Mat map1, map2, out_img;
map1 = cv::imread("map1.bmp", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
map2 = cv::imread("map2.bmp", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
map1.convertTo(map1, CV_32FC1);
map2.convertTo(map2, CV_32FC1);
cv::remap(in_img, out_img, map1, map2, cv::INTER_CUBIC, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
```

But i get a black image (out_img). Everything works fine if i calculate map1 and map2 in runtime, but it tooks much more time than loading from file.
I also tried to store maps as xml files, but it is much more slowly.
So my question is: is there any way to not to calculate map1 and map2 everytime i want to use remap()?

Comment: rather use the 16bit integer version of those maps, and save / load them as png

Comment: @berak Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I still get the black output  image.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, here is my solution:

- after initUndistortRectifyMap you will get map1 and map2 as CV_32FC1
- calculate the respective min and max values for each map and store them (they will be used later on to aid in the rescaling)
- normalize the map (normalize(map1,map1,0,255, cv::NORM_MINMAX)), convert it to CV_8UC1 (convertTo(map1, CV_8UC1)) and then store it
- load the map and the min and max values, use convertTo(map1, CV_32FC1) and afterwards normalize(map1,map1,minMap1,maxMap2, cv::NORM_MINMAX).
- load the image you want to undistort and apply the previously loaded map.

Used .png instead of .bmp. Beware that going from CV_32FC1 to CV_8UC1 and back to CV_32FC1 makes the image smoother.
Performance was about 7x faster than using undistort.
Hope it helps!

Comment: if you're squeezing those maps into 8 bits, be prepared for serious banding/discretization artefacts. better to use a file format that supports floats or 16 bit channels.

Comment: You are definitely right, this was the best solution I came up with so far using only openCV. In OpenCV documentation for the imwrite function (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce ) suggests using tiff or exr.
In my case, I tried using tiff or exr but it didn't work maybe because of my OpenCV version (I cannot use other libraries as well). You can output the map in CV_16UC2 instead of CV_32FC1 but how would you convert next to 16-bit unsigned to save it, as far as I know imwrite only stores 1,3,4 channel images.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other options.

Generally, `imread` requires the `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag or else it helpfully converts things into 3-channel 8-bit.

###### Save as TIFF, which natively supports float32

That requires you to save each map individually because `imwrite` doesn't want to save a 2-channel image (np.dstack). Or you insert a third channel with nothing important in it.

This also assumes that OpenCV was built with support for TIFF. I hear that's not always the case but it's rare.

###### use `convertMaps` to obtain 16-bit values

And store in any format that can store 16 bit data without loss (PNG, TIFF). convertMaps returns one `16SC2` map containing the integer parts and a `16UC1` map containing fractional parts (practically 10 bit for 5+5 bit interpolation lookup table).

```py
# have xmap, ymap

(imap, fmap) = cv.convertMaps(map1=xmap, map2=ymap, dstmap1type=cv.CV_16SC2)
stacked = np.dstack([imap.astype(np.uint16), fmap])

# imwrite

# imread with IMREAD_UNCHANGED flag

imap = stacked[:,:,0:2].astype(np.int16)
fmap = stacked[:,:,2]
(xmap2, ymap2) = cv.convertMaps(map1=imap, map2=fmap, dstmap1type=cv.CV_32FC1)

# assert np.allclose(xmap, xmap2) and np.allclose(ymap, ymap2)
```